# Complex excel problem, parse string then get max date from cell next to matching cell

Tags: excel

Below I have one or more strings in cells D7 D8 and D9 separated by a comma. I would like to get the max date corresponding to the numbers provided.

```
---      Col A   Col B 
Row 1    number  date  
Row 2    1.0    1/1/2018    
Row 3    1.1    1/2/2018
Row 4    1.3    1/5/2018
Row 5    1.6    1/3/2018
Row 6    1.8    1/4/2018

text string in cell D7 = 1.1,1.6 
output = 1/3/2018

text string in cell D8 = 1.1
output = 1/2/2018

text string in cell D9 = 1.8,1.6,1.3
output = 1/5/2018
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=MAX(INDEX(B:B,N(IF({1},MATCH(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(D2,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(D2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),A:A,0)))))
```

Being an array formula one must first put the formula in the First cell then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode, then copy down the dataset.

[image]

---

Another using SUMIFS:

```
=MAX(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(D2,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(D2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99))))
```

Still an array formula